# How to hide navbar in login, register page in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hi i want to hide the navbar when entering login or registration page

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        {publicRoutes.map((route, index) => {
          const Pages = route.component;
          return <Route key={index} path={route.path} element={<Pages />} />;
        })}
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

routes

```
const publicRoutes = [
  { path: "/", component: Home },
  { path: "/login", component: Login },
  { path: "/register", component: Register },
  { path: "/forgot", component: ForgotPassword },
  { path: "/products", component: Products },
  { path: "/products/:id", component: SingleProduct },
  { path: "/help", component: Help },
];

export { publicRoutes };
```

please help me. this is my first time using stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Because `Navbar` is directly above `Routes` inside `Router`, it will appear on every routes.

A better approach to this problem is to create a layout component.

```
import React, { PropsWithChildren } from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div>{children}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

For other pages you want to display the navbar, for example a home page, it would be

```
import React from "react";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>Hello World</div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

For login page or register pages, you don't need to nest your JSX elements inside layout. Also, don't forget to remove `Navbar` from you `App` components. Hope it helps :)